# What should be the default value for a not Null Unique field

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am adding a field to an existing model:

```
...
booking_id = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=5)
...
```

Now when I run `./manage makemigrations`, ask for a default value. This value is created in a `pre_save` signal. What should I give as default value in this case?

Obviously if I give a default value, when I run `./manage migrate` this raises `django.db.utils.IntegrityError`

Comment: Is there a way you could do the stuff you do in `pre_save` in a callable?

Comment: If I don't use a pre_save I would need to query db.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the field with `null=True`, and create a migration. Then add a data migration to populate the field. Finally, set `null=False` and create a final migration to add the `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: I've always hated this feature of the ORM.  Especially when it demands this of an empty table ......

Comment: @Beltiras for an empty table, can't you set `null=True` then specify anything you want as the default. Since there aren't any rows, the unique constraint won't be broken.

Comment: @Gocht Unless you can move the code to calculate the id from the `pre_save` to a callable, I'm not aware of a simpler way. It's not too tricky. There might be several steps, but each step is straight forward.

Comment: @Alasdair I have been working with this flow. Today, I faced this situation again and I though: "_I'll ask for a different/better way to do this_", but seems there's not yet one.

Comment: I can't recall ever having not had to do some gymnastics when migrating the schema.  That includes a lot of times when I was doing original modeling, didn't have to think about earlier data.  Adding an option to the migration command signifying a hard reset would be useful (it may even be there, I was using south before we had native migrations).